# How to create tab without closing the popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When I create a tab from popup, popup window will close, bc selected is true. The new tab is selected:

```
chrome.tabs.create({'url': 'http://www.google.com', 'selected' : true });
```

When `selected` is `false`, popup remains, but new tab hasn't been focused:

```
chrome.tabs.create({'url': 'http://www.google.com', 'selected' : false });
```

How to combine this, having the new tab AND the popup visible at the same time? I played around with `chrome.tabs.move`, but I feel I'm on the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but in case anyone else needs this too. I found a way around the 
API: If you first set the current tab to pinned, then create/remove/select other tabs in other windows, then unpin the current tab, the current tab will remain open, and as a result the popup will not close.

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){

    const currentTab = tabs[0];

    // pin the current tab:
    chrome.tabs.update(currentTab.id, {pinned: true}, function(t){

        // do what you need to do here:
        chrome.tabs.update(someTabId, {}, function(){

        // un-pin the current tab
        chrome.tabs.update(currentTab.id, {pinned: false});
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no way keeping the popup opened while you select another window.

If you want to defer selecting the window, you can first create it, and when your ready, you can select it with [chrome.tabs.update](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-update).

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://www.google.com', selected: false}, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {selected: true});
});
```

Comment: Mohamed, I implemented but the POPUP CLOSES :((

Comment: horiworld: Yes, the popup should close cause you are now focused in another tab/window. There is absolutely no way to keep that popup opened while selecting another window/tab.